# How to treat or beautify R summary() output containing "e+02" (scientific notation) values?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and wan't to learn what is a good way to treat "e+02" values.
See this example output of a `summary(lm())`.

```
Coefficients:
                                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                 -2.168e+02  4.402e+00 -49.257  < 2e-16 ***
Age                                          1.044e+01  8.403e-02 124.262  < 2e-16 ***
GenderWeiblich                               2.638e+02  6.131e+00  43.019  < 2e-16 ***
VerstorbenTrue                               1.027e+03  3.665e+01  28.020  < 2e-16 ***
```

Of course I know what that `e+` means but I don't want to transform that in my head. I want to beautify the output.

Asking the other way around: Why does R use scientific notation at this point?

Comment: do you mean for reading onscreen or are you planning to export to some kind of report?

Comment: First on screen. Currently I "export" them via `sink()`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: `options("scipen"=n)` - Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation (if fixed notation is more than n digits wider then scientific will be preferred) - I don't know if this will work for all cases as I assume some custom print methods may ignore this.  setting scipen to 999 effectively disables scientific notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to eliminate the exponential notation of the integer, we can use the

global setting using [`options()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/options) method, by setting the scipen argument, that is

```
options(scipen = n)
```